# error: not found: type SparkConf

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I installed spark. pre-compiled and standalone. But both are unable to run `val conf = new SparkConf()`. The error is `error: not found: type SparkConf`:

```
scala> val conf = new SparkConf()
<console>:10: error: not found: type SparkConf
```

The pre-compiled is spark 0.9.1 and Scala 2.10.3
The standalone is Spark 1.0.1 and Scala 2.10.4
For the standalone, i compiled it with scala 2.10.4
Your help will be much appreciated

Comment: Have you imported it to the scope: `import org.apache.spark.SparkConf`? If yes, do you have Spark on classpath?

Answer (score 20):

As we pointed out in comments, your code lacks appropriate import statement:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
```